# Map list and return items in a ListView

Tags: flutter

I want to map the list snapshot.data.berichte and return it in a ListView.
I am getting an error because of "item" and unfortunately don't know how to solve the problem.
It worked before, so maybe flutter changed the syntax for this..

```
                return ListView(
                  children: snapshot.data.berichte.map(item =>{
                    if (item.team == team)
                    {
                      return Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: double.infinity,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      child: Card(
                      ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the `=>` arrow and add parentheses around the argument for full functions:

```dart
stView(
    children: snapshot.data.berichte.map((item) { // HERE 
    if (item.team == team)
    {
    return Container(
    width: double.infinity,
    height: double.infinity,
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
    child: Card(
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but then I get this error: "The argument type 'Iterable<Container>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>"

Comment: You have to convert `Iterable` (which is the output of `map`) to `List`. To do so, simply use the `toList()` method of the `Iterable` class: `snapshot.data.berichte.map(...).toList()`